# Execute Command not work in Java

Tags: java, process, exec

Execute Command worked well in Terminal, but not in Java code.

```
    String cmd = "find -name javax.jar";
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            process.getInputStream()));

    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println("" + line);
    }
    System.out.println("Line : "+line);
```

Comment: What do you mean by _not work_?

Comment: Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: I execute the command in terminal. It gives the location. But from Java it gives null

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you spawn a process with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

the process is started from the same working directory as the Java process. If Java was run from a different working directory than you ran the `find -name javax.jar` in console, you will see different results.

Comment: Both the jar and Java is in the same Directory.

Comment: @newuser What was the current working directory when you ran the command in console? What was the current working directory when you launched java?

Comment: Both are in root directory

Comment: name@IM-WS-U-35:~$ find -name javax.jar
./MyFIles/MyTest/javax.jar
name@IM-WS-U-35:~$

Comment: It gives the exact location when i tried in terminal   "./MyFIles/MyTest/javax.jar"

Comment: @newuser Try printing out from the error `InputStream` and try doing a `Process#waitFor()` and checking the value returned.

Comment: I tried to get the process.getErrorStream(), it doesn't give any error, it gives null. Process#waitFor() gives 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Now i tried the following command find /home -name javax.jar. It gives the Error find: `/home/workstationadmin/.dbus': Permission denied. I am not having permission so only i am not able to access. Thanks for spending your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

i think you may try to add the path of find.
like find /var/tmp -name